# Wordpress website not working properly after installing SSL certificate

Tags: php, wordpress, http, ssl, https

I have installed the `SSL` certificate via `Cpanel` to my `WP` website. But right after installing it the `UI` of the website got disturbed.

**Without SSL**

[image]

**With SSL**

[image]

**Update  1**

I have looked into it and found out that `CSS/JS` is not properly loaded. So I changed `HTTP to` HTTPS in my files where I was using it. But still, the issue is the same. Moreover, I am getting the below errors in my console.

[image]

Any help would  be highly appreciated

Comment: Looks like CSS isn't loaded for some reason. Search in the browser's console to see what's going on.

Comment: @OlafDietsche yes you are right CSS/JS not loading :|

Comment: Perhaps links to your css/js resources are using different histname?

Comment: Maybe search for [ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID). I would guess, the URL for CSS and JS is different from your main URL. Compare these and see what's different between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Its due to references of css/images/javascript etc that are not using the SSL (https) but use HTTP instead. I recommend to install [Really Simple SSL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/) plugin for the quickest solution. Another solution is to go and fix every incorrect reference but this can be a lot of work and may in some cases need advanced knowledge (editing database entries etc.)

Comment: ps. if you are using wordpress 5.7 or above there now is a solution in the wordpress core for this [Improved HTTPS detection and migration in WordPress 5.7](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/02/22/improved-https-detection-and-migration-in-wordpress-5-7/)

Comment: Ok, looking at the error it shows the name in the certificate does not match the domain. Make sure the website is on a subdomain this is included in the certificate for example if your website is on blog.example.com the certificate needs to contain that information. you can use this tool on SSL hopper to [test your certificate](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check with your hosting company to properly configure HTTPS Redirects. The hosting company may ask you to install an HTTPS redirect plugin on your website. If that's work out then good if not, then go to PHPmyAdmin of your cPanel and Export your database. Open the database in Notepad++ and replace all http with https . Save the file. Delete old database tables. Import the file you saved with changes. Be aware, it might break your site, so be sure to take a backup of your database before attempting it. If things don't work out, revert the changes and take the help of a developer to fix it for you.